policy not scanning in wazuh
I found the Bursa malaysia policy document in online and convert it to yml the wazuh cannot scan the policy.
I changed the policy document to yml and put it in sca but it did not scan. I also tried to use a old sca file and replaced it with new configuration but other than the name everything still stays the same.
